# Hermitian operators in Dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction

Imagine if we have a Hermitian operator $\hat{O}$ which we can write in position basis $O(x)$.

Here we take $\psi$ to be wave function and $|x\rangle$ to be the position eigenstate.

I was wondering if the following statements are true:

> $$\langle x|\hat O|\psi\rangle=O(x)\psi(x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\langle x|\hat O|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|\hat O|x\rangle$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an operator that is a function of the position and momentum operators $\hat O=\hat O(\hat X,\hat P)$, then using the completeness of the position basis we can express $\langle x|\hat O|\psi\rangle$ as

$$\langle x|\hat O|\psi\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\langle x|\hat O|x'\rangle\langle x'|\psi\rangle\,\text dx'$$

and since $\langle x|\hat O(\hat X,\hat P)|x'\rangle=O\left(x',-i\hbar\frac{\text d}{\text dx'}\right)\delta(x'-x)$ the integral becomes

\begin{align}
\langle x|\hat O|\psi\rangle &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty O\left(x',-i\hbar\frac{\text d}{\text dx'}\right)\delta(x'-x)\langle x'|\psi\rangle\,\text dx\\
&=O\left(x,-i\hbar\frac{\text d}{\text dx}\right)\langle x|\psi\rangle\\
&=O\left(x,-i\hbar\frac{\text d}{\text dx}\right)\psi(x)
\end{align}

In general $\langle x|\hat O|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle \psi|\hat O|x\rangle$ are complex conjugates, i.e. $\langle x|\hat O|\psi\rangle=\langle \psi|\hat O|x\rangle^*$

Comment: I have no enountered 'completeness of the position basis', what does the mean?

Comment: @JackJack It is the idea that the any state can be expressed as a linear combination of position basis states. The expression is $$\int|x\rangle\langle x|\,\text dx=1$$ Or in the discrete case for a complete basis $$\sum_n|n\rangle\langle n|=1$$